# Ограничение парсинга телеграмма

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, бот

Есть задача - спарсить n-ое количество сообщений из телеграмм каналов. Использовал такой скрипт:

```
import random
import requests
import xlrd
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="root",
                              host="127.0.0.1",
                              port="5432",
                              database="botgethist")

cursor = connection.cursor()

data = xlrd.open_workbook("D:/RED.xlsx")
data = data.sheet_by_index(0)
lkdt = []
lkcol = [0, 1, 3]

for v in range(0, data.nrows):
    lkp = []
    for pks in lkcol:
        lkp.append(str(data.cell_value(v, pks)).strip())
    lkp.insert(2, "ru")
    lkdt.append(lkp)

request_delay = 2
requests_per_minute = 30
seconds_per_minute = 60
last_request_time = time.time()

proxies_list = [
    {"http": "http://Qvnb7L:zUGdas@217.29.62.214:10061"},
    {"http": "http://Qvnb7L:zUGdas@217.29.62.214:10060"},
    {"http": "http://Qvnb7L:zUGdas@217.29.62.214:10059"},
    {"http": "http://Qvnb7L:zUGdas@217.29.62.214:10058"},
    {"http": "http://Qvnb7L:zUGdas@217.29.62.214:10057"}
]

token = "1779257401:AAHNOrRslVlNtTHxkb45uJgxWro-dvaLBrs"

for k in range(len(lkdt)):
    try:
        current_time = time.time()
        time_since_last_request = current_time - last_request_time

        if time_since_last_request < seconds_per_minute / requests_per_minute:
            time.sleep(seconds_per_minute / requests_per_minute - time_since_last_request)

        sk = lkdt[k]
        ids = "@" + str(sk[1]).split("/")[-1]
        url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/getChat?chat_id={1}".format(token, ids)
        s = requests.post(url, proxies=random.choice(proxies_list)).json()

        if str(s["ok"]) == "True":
            sk.append(int(s["result"]["id"]))
            lkdt[k] = tuple(sk)
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tgchannels (tgchannels_name, tgchannels_url, tgchannels_lang, tgchannels_country, tgchannels_idchan) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", lkdt[k])
            print(str(k + 1) + "   " + str(len(lkdt))
        else:
            print(s)
            if str(s['description']).startswith("Too Many Requests:") == True:
                print(str(k + 1) + "   " + str(len(lkdt)) + "   Error : many requests")
                time.sleep(10)
            if str(s['description']) == "Bad Request: chat not found":
                print(str(k + 1) + "   " + str(len(lkdt)) + "   Error : chat not found")
                time.sleep(10)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print(sk)
        time.sleep(30)

connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Но постоянно утыкаюсь в ограничение после 206 канала. Что делать? Какие варианты? Может через телетон переписать?

Comment: Подробнее, не совсем понятно, что у вас не получается? И отформатируйте вопрос нормально, пожалуйста, а то можете наловить минусов)

Comment: Я тут недавно, не совсем понимаю что не так с форматированием)

Comment: Подробнее опишу проблему: при запуске парсинга всё идёт хорошо вплоть до 206 канала из базы. После этого возникает ошибка 429 Too Many Requests. Уже и прокси подключал, ничего не помогает.